# Why can't I interact with form objects from within the main program?

Tags: c#, winforms

This should be pretty straightforward, yet I am struggling to see any results.

I have the following form code:

```
//Form1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NotepadRW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected TextBox textReadInfo;
        public void SetReadInfo(String str)
        {
            txtReadInfo.Text = str;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the following program code:

```
//Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NotepadRW
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form1);

            form1.SetReadInfo("Hi");

        }
    }
}
```

Which result in the following form:

[image: Blank Form]

Why is it not displaying the string I provide it? Am I not properly understanding how the program works with a windows form? Does execution of the Main() method of Program.cs stop when the new instance of Form1 is called?

Note: I've tried this with a text box and a rich text box. Same results.

Extra points:
Am I following encapsulation correctly? I was going to modify the text box to be publicly accessible (which will work), but I thought this would be the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: Is `txtReadInfo.Text = str` simply misspelled or is txtReadInfo defined somewhere we can't see?

Comment: Why don't you do `this.SetReadInfo("Hi")` after `InitializeComponent` call?

Comment: You are assigning that text *after* Application.Run. That starts the GUI event loop and does not exit until the main form closes. Move that line between form constructor and Application run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is not obvious from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Application.Run(Form)` method blocks. You can infer this from the following quote:

> The Dispose method of the Form class will be called prior to the return of this method.

This means that the form will do its thing and it has to be done doing its thing before `Run` will return. I.e., it blocks.

You can accomplish what you want by switching up the order though. Instead of

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
form1.SetReadInfo("Hi");
```

try

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.SetReadInfo("Hi");
Application.Run(form1);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking when I said the following `"Does execution of the Main() method of Program.cs stop when the new instance of Form1 is called?"` So is program.cs useless other than to run the Form itself? Should the majority of my work be done inside the Form1.cs code in most programs? (As simple as they may be, including this one)

Comment: Depends on the application. For a simple Windows Forms application, yes, it is probably simplest to put everything in your main form, since the UX is going to be forms-centric.  You'd use the application class more if you are expecting to have multiple threads right out of the gate, or if your application lacks a "main" form.

Comment: You have seriously improved my comprehension of this. I deeply appreciate your quick and elaborate responses.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be making your text box public, otherwise you may get cross thread execution exception.

The reason your code is not working is because you are running the form on the main thread, so anything after Application.Run() does not get executed. You can run your form on a separate thread.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 form = new Form1();

            System.Threading.Thread workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Application.Run(form));

            workerThread.Start();

            form.SetReadInfo("Hello");
```

Comment: This is a fantastic trick and will be useful to me in the future. I am certain of that. Since this is a single thread application, requiring minimal computing power, I have selected John's answer for this question. Your answer, however, will be my starting point once I move into multi-threaded applications. Thank you.